# If A is a non-linear operator, can the solutions to Ax = b still be written as “general solution=particular solution + homogeneous solutions”?

Tags: linear-algebra

If A is a non-linear operator, can the solutions to Ax = b still be written as “general solution=particular solution + homogeneous solutions”? Provide examples.

I'm having trouble coming up with an ideal example of a non-linear operator.

Please help.

Comment: No.  That's a characteristic property of linear operators (though I wouldn't rule out that some particular nonlinear operator has that property, it certainly isn't guaranteed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at an example of a linear operator to see *why* that property holds:

$\frac d{dx} y +y = x$.  The linear operator in this case is $A=\frac d{dx} + \Bbb 1$.  So if we have a solution to the general homogeneous case, say $y_g$ and we have a particular solution to the nonhomogeneous case $y_p$, then $ky_g + y_p$ *must* also be a solution, for *any* real number $k$.  That's because $A(ky_g +y_p)=kA(y_g)+A(y_p)=0+x=x$.  Notice that this *completely* relies on $A$ being an linear operator.

For an example of a nonlinear operator that doesn't have this property consider $A'=(\frac d{dx})^2 + \Bbb 1$.  Confirm for yourself that $y_g=-\frac 14(x^2-2x+1)$ solves the equation $A'y = (\frac {dy}{dx})^2 + y=0$.  Now let's change the RHS by about the least amount we can: let's make it a $1$ instead of a $0$.  So our nonhomogeneous equation is $A'y=1$.  Confirm for yourself that $y_p=-\frac 14x^2+1$ solves this.

Now let's add those two solutions together: $y=y_p+y_g= -\frac 14(2x^2-2x-3)$.  Now plug this into $A'y=1$ to see that this is NOT a solution to this nonlinear equation.

Comment: thank you So much. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $A$ is any operator that is one-to-one and onto, with $A(0) = 0$.  Thus for any $b$ there is a unique "particular solution" $x_b$ with $A(x_b) = b$.  All solutions of $A(x) = b$ are of the form $x_b + x_0$, where $x_0 = 0$ is the only solution of the homogeneous equation.

An example of a nonlinear operator of this form is $A(x) = x^3$ on $\mathbb R$, or on a space of real-valued functions.